# L’expression « ça m'a juste échappé » au sens de "it just sort of slipped out"

Tags: expressions

Si je fais une boulette en disant quelques gros mots dans le feu de l'action, j’utiliserai l’expression « ça m'a (juste) échappé, désolé », essayant de rectifier le tir.

Je me demande si elle peut être considérée comme raccourci de « ça a échappé ***de la bouche de moi*** », ou simplement comme « ça a échappé ***à moi*** » ?

Comment: Plutôt que les barbarismes *de la bouche de moi* et *ça a échappé à moi*, j'écrirais que l'alternative est entre *ça s'est échappé de ma bouche* et *ça s'est échappé de moi/ ça a échappé à ma surveillance/mon contrôle*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ça m'a (juste) échappé" peut effectivement avoir deux sens :

- ça a échappé à mon attention/mon regard/ma surveillance (pour te reprendre : "ça a échappé à moi", mais attention cette phrase ne se dit pas): dans le sens "escape from"

par exemple : "s'il y a des fautes dans mes réponses sur ce forum, c'est que ça m'a échappé"

- ça a échappé : dans le sens "les mots sont sortis de ma bouche de manière incontrôlée" (pour te reprendre : "ça a échappé de la bouche de moi", pareil, cela ne se dit pas non plus), soit le sens "it just sort of slipped out"

c'est donc ici ton exemple : "oh m**** ! Désolée, ça m'a échappé !
ou encore : "je ne voulais trahir ton secret, ça m'a échappé"

Comment: Why repeat the mistake? de la bouche de moi? No one would say that.

Comment: That why I put brackets and quotations marks on and correct it by "les mots sont sortis de ma bouche de manière incontrôlée" ;) I only used it again so Alone-zee would understand better. But thanks to note it.

Comment: Better to correct it at least. Brackets don't imply mistakes.

Comment: Done, I edited it.